# How to fix "cannot access class sun.awt.AppContext (in module java.desktop)" in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am having the following error when calling the AppContext class:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class [Class Name] (in unnamed module @0x6f1fba17) cannot access class sun.awt.AppContext (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x6f1fba17
    at [Class Name].run([Class Name].java:176)
```

Line 176 contains the following line of code:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppContext.class);
```

I tried to uninstall java and reinstall it.

Also, I removed the use '--release' option as shown below:

[image: use '--release option']

Comment: That error is what’s supposed to happen.  Internal sun.* classes are private to a Java implementation and are not supposed to be accessed by applications.  Is there a reason you think you need to use that class directly?

Comment: Actually, my mistake was that I had to access "AppConfig.class" instead of the "AppContext.class".